# Building an IPA file with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have a app and have successfully built it with Xcode. The problem is I want to test this application on my iPad. I know there is Apple developer program and stuff. But before going there I wanted to try this app first. There is a website called testflightapp.com where we can deploy applications to iPad on the fly.

That requires a IPA file. How do I go about it ?

Comment: You can't run apps on devices without being a developer.

Comment: Unless it's jailbroken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directions for that are at http://support.testflightapp.com/kb/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ipa.  You might need to be in the developer program to create a valid IPA file, though.

Comment: Link was broken, but found the directions here:  http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/494413-how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4-3-

Comment: Apple has taken down all of these articles since purchasing TestFlight. Archived version: https://web.archive.org/web/20150209063308/http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/494413-how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4-3-

Answer (score 9):

You can create an IPA file in Xcode with "Build -> Build and Archive". Now open "Window -> Organizer" and you find the IPA in the section "Archived Applications". Save the IPA to a folder now.

IMPORTANT: You have to be an Apple developer to create an IPA file. The IPA file have to be signed with certificates, etc. ...

Comment: Iam using Xcode 4.2 with iOS 5 and while opening xcode->product, i can see only build with no sub tabs and another option, build for-> testing, profiling, running and i am unable to select build for archiving.

Answer (score 7):

Put your ad-hoc profile before archiving the project. Once you are ready.

Go to Product ---->Archive  upon successful archiving you will see Organizer Window Navigate through to

Archives then click on Distrubition next window you need to choose Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployent then you will choose your AdHoc profile and save.

[image: .ipa creation]

Answer (score 0):

To load an app on a physical device you MUST be an Apple developer, it is not optional.

Once you have your account, you will need to enter your device IDs and generate a certificate against those device IDs at developer.apple.com

The certificate is used to sign the IPA and allow it to run on the pre-defined devices.